# "Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile]" error

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, sni

After recently upgrading Apache2 to version 2.2.31 I found a strange behaviour in SSL VirtualHost setup.

A few of the website I'm hosting were showing the certificate for the default host even if the client was `Server Name Identification` aware, and this happened only with a few of them. This shows as the common Firefox's/Chrome's passport-warning about you being possibly scammed if you're browsing your home banking, but that simply was not the case.

To be clear, if server `host.hostingdomain.org` has its own SSL, attempting to access `https://www.hostedsite.org` reports certificate for `host.hostingdomain.org`, but a few `https://www.hostedsite.me` reported the correct certificate.

All sites are hosted on the same IP address, on port 443. The truth is that VirtualHosting works on the HTTP side and redirects SNI-aware clients to SSL automatically, so it's backward compatible with SNI-unaware clients.

Examining error logs for the offending VirtualHosts shown the following text

```
[Tue Dec 25 16:02:45 2012] [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] (/path/to/www.site.org.conf:20)
```

and in fact the vhost was correctly configured with SSLCertificateFile.

The question is obvious: how to fix that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It happens that it could be a bug in the most recent version of Apache.

### Solution 1: downgrade to the latest stable

### Solution 2: edit `listen.conf`

Replace `Listen *:443` (or `Listen 443` according to your setup) with `Listen *:443 http`

[Credit](http://www.aliov.org/123/server-should-be-ssl-aware-but-has-no-certificate-configured-hint-sslcertificatefile-null0/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! You saved me a lot of wondering around... I wonder why apache is making life harder!?

Comment: Solution 2: should that be httpd.conf not listen.conf

Comment: Note, this happened to me this morning... ended up I needed to add that "http" to the listen lin in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf - oh, I did not have to downgrade...

Comment: Solutions are alternate, you don't need to downgrade if adding listen.conf

Answer (score 11):

I had the same exact problem, and what worked for me was unbelievably simple

edit /etc/apache2/ports.conf (for ubuntu, or httpd.conf )

change "Listen 443" to "Listen 443 http" under ssl_module

Comment: This is already in the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer seems outdated. This answer was more useful and accurate. +1

Comment: This answer is applicable for apache on my apache2.4 lamp stack, ubuntu.

Other answer is "listen.conf" - should be ports.conf

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this is to ensure that all of your :443 vhosts include the TLS configuration.

This problem was recently [introduced in Debian wheezy](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775129) and I got the solution from http://blog.noizeramp.com/2010/10/03/apache-2-and-ssl-configuration/.

Comment: This was my problem. I duplicated a vhost in my `httpd.conf` but failed to include the lines specifying the TLS configuration. Adding the various TLS settings back in (SSLEngine, SSLCipherSuite, SSLCertificateFile, and SSLCertificateKeyFile) fixed the problem.