# SSL Fault, Apache won't start

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-2.4, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, mod-ssl

After installing an SSL certificate from Comodo following [these instructions](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9423/0/apache-opensslmodssl), I've found that apache will no longer start. This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName latimer.io
    ServerAlias *.latimer.io
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/latimer.io/html

#       RewriteEngine On
#       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName latimer.io
    ServerAlias *.latimer.io
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/latimer.io/html

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/server.key.secure
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/latimer_io.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/latimer_io.ca-bundle
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error log gives the following (not very helpful) errors:

```
[ssl:emerg] [pid 30910] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
[ssl:emerg] [pid 30910] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

Yet running apache2ctl -S produces no errors. Any guidance as to how to proceed is appreciated. Other serverfault pages describing the same, generic error have not been successful in resolving the problem.

Comment: Run `openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/ssl/latimer_io.crt`to check whether your certificate is correctly stored in the file whence you told Apache to load it.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured \[Hint: SSLCertificateFile\]" error](http://serverfault.com/questions/460876/server-should-be-ssl-aware-but-has-no-certificate-configured-hint-sslcertific)

Comment: Certificate is correctly stored, that's the first thing I checked. This is not a duplicate; just because they report the same generic error does not mean the thing that causes them are the same. I know how to use Google...

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled apache and the problem was fixed. Something must have been corrupted.